# Encrypting PIN without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, brute-force, penetration-testing

This is our dilemma. We have an app that uses JavaScript to encrypt an entered PIN value. The risk here is the encryption is exposed to the public. Although it is secured because it uses asymmetric key encryption, it is still susceptible to a brute force attack. Something like attacker entering PIN values as trial and error, encrypting it then submitting the request. So as not to allow an attacker to get hold of the encryption logic, we need another way to hide this. Moving the encryption logic to the back end would allow the PIN to be exposed during submission (e.g. can be seen by browser request interceptors).

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Something like attacker entering PIN values as trial and error, encrypting it then submitting the request. - This is actually the main purpose of encryption. People always misunderstood that if the value is encrypted it can't be hack? we encrypt values to make attacker have a hard time guessing the real value, its to delay the attackers only, to provide developer a time to take action

Comment: Just use HTTPS. Interception by debugging tools are not an issue because the person who runs the debugger owns the PIN number

Comment: Isn't this what SSL is for?  Submit over an HTTPS connection and then store it securely on the server.

Comment: Another thing is always put encryption on back end, otherwise it will be useless because attacker can see client side codes

Comment: thanks for the inputs.  @slebetman: yes but can history of debugging tools be accessed to possibly retrieve the pin?

Answer (score 1):

Never put your encryption on the client side, you need to do back-end encryption or your logic will get compromised.

Always use HTTPS when you are transfering sensitive information to protect it from 3rd-party.